# getting 2's complement from a hex string value in java

Tags: java, string, hex

i have a hex value "FF30" in string format.i need the two's complement value of this number.now i am doing,first converting it to binary then taking the 2's complement.is there is any simple way.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to *apply* the 2's complement operation to this value, or do you need to just interpret it as a 2's complement number?  If the latter, then skip the second line of code below.

I think this will work for you.

```
 int val = Integer.parseInt("FF30", 16);
 int result = (~val) + 1;
```

**Update**

Since you imply in your comments that you want the result converted back to a string, that's a simple matter of calling "toHexString" and chopping off any padded bits that were prefixed

```
    String hex = "FF30";

    int length = hex.length();


    long value = Long.parseLong(hex,  16);  // convert hex string to long
    long result = (~value) + 1;             // compute the 2's complement

    // convert the result value back to a hex string (keeping the same length and dropping any sign-extension bits)
    String resultAsString = Long.toHexString(result);

    // chop off the prefix of the string so the result is the same length as the input
    int newLength = resultAsString.length();
    if (newLength > length)
    {
        resultAsString = resultAsString.substring(newLength-length);
    }

    System.out.print(resultAsString);
```

Comment: Here first two bytes forms the value => FF30 H => FF30 H – 1 =FF2F H
Now take 1’s compliment of above value =>00D0 H  this is actually i need to do.

Comment: @user3336240 - you never stated in your question that you needed the result to be a string.  But I've updated my answer to account for that.